# Python, alternate list by index

Tags: python, list, indexing, schedule

I have a problem about a python system that has a schedule of 7 days, each day is the index of this list. The problem is that we have a 24 hours schedule, so each week schedule should alternate like in the picture. One of the rule is that the first week on range always finish on the 6 (Sunday), and the end date of the week can finish in any day.

Maybe I'm seeing this in a harder way that it really is. I hope some help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Can you share code that has the problem? Your schedule seems to simply alternate between 'Miguel' and 'Juanita' with Miguel taking the shift on odd days in odd weeks and even days in even weeks and the other way around for Juanita?

Comment: Please don't share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11301900. As @Grismar wrote, there doesn't seem to be an actual question here.

Comment: Why do the red weeks end with `1` instead of `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works:

```
days = 7 
weeks = 4
schedule = [(d+ w%2)%days + int((d+w%2)>(days-1)) for w in range(weeks) for d in range(days)]`
```

Which essentially says that if it's an odd week (w%2 = 1) add one to the normal schedule and don't allow the final day to be equal to 0, which is why I add the int((d+w%2)>(days-1)) term.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the iteration variable is even or odd, and append the appropriate list to the result.

```
result = []
for i in range(5):
    if i % 2 == 0: 
        result += list(range(7))
    else:
        result += list(range(1, 7)) + [1]
print(result)
```